# Geometric meaning of the arc length function?

Tags: calculus, analysis, geometry, soft-question

Let $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and let $\varphi: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuously differentiable. Then the indefinite integral $x \mapsto \int_a^x \| \varphi'(t)\| \, dt$ on $[a,b]$ is the arc length function of the curve $\varphi [a,b]$. 
But what is the geometric meaning of this function? Using informal language or picture to describe it suffices.

Answer (score 3):

That is not the **definition** of arc length.  Rather, a **theorem** says that that integral gives the arc length in cases in which $\varphi$ is differentiable.

Suppose $a=x_0 < x_1 < x_2<\cdots<x_{n-1}<x_n=b$, so that the sequence $x_0,\ldots,x_n$ is a partition of the interval $[a,b]$. The sum
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \|\varphi(x_{i+1}) - \varphi(x_i)\|
$$
is the length of a polygonal path that follows a straight line from $\varphi(x_0)$ to $\varphi(x_1)$, then a straight line from $\varphi(x_1)$ to $\varphi(x_2)$, then a straight line from $\varphi(x_2)$ to $\varphi(x_3)$, and so on, until it reachs $\varphi(x_n)=\varphi(b)$.  The **arc length** is at least as big as the length of every such polygonal path.  But it is no bigger than it has to be in order to be at least as big as the length of **every** such polygonal path.

Comment: Thank you. I think I am silent on asserting that it is the definition; and I believe my question does not imply that I take it as a definition :) I know the argument to define arc length from polygon sequences.